# How to download firefox with bash?

Tags: bash, firefox

I need to download and run a firefox through a bash script, so I tried running the commands below:

```sh
curl -o ~/firefox.tar.bz2 https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64
tar xjf ~/firefox.tar.bz2
~/firefox/firefox
```

Yet already the first command fails to download the tar file.

Note: The OS is Ubuntu 16, and I don't want to use `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the address, otherwise the shell interprets the ampersand as a shell order and it ends up trying to download something different to what you expect. Also, add the `-L` parameter to tell cURL to follow the links:

```
curl -L -o ~/firefox.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64"
```